# Display Tree Data in Table with Material-UI in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, datatable, material-ui, treetable

I am currently working on a small project, in this project I use a tree structure Table as shown!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYivg.png)

As in the picture is the Table in the old project, I use the Ant Design library (with code support on the homepage), so it is hardly difficult to create such a Table. The code form is as follows:

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: '', dataIndex: 'name', key: 'name', width: '20%'
  },
  {
    title: '', dataIndex: 'User1', key: 'User1', width: '10%',
  },
  {
    title: '', dataIndex: 'User2', width: '10%', key: 'User2',
  }
];

const data = [
  {
    key: 1,
    name: <h3 style={{ fontSize: "16px", color: "white" }}>Module 1</h3>,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    name: <h3 style={{ fontSize: "16px", color: "white", }} className="level0">Module 2</h3>,
    children: [
      {
        key: 21,
        name: <p style={{ fontSize: "14px", color: "white" }}>Function name</p>,
        User1: <p style={{ fontSize: "14px", color: "white" }}>User 1</p>,
        User2: <p style={{ fontSize: "14px", color: "white" }}>User 2</p>,
        children: [
          {
            key: 211,
            name: <p style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>Function 1</p>,
            User1: '',
            User2: '',
            children: [
              {
                key: 2111,
                name: <p>Feature 1</p>,
                User1: <Checkbox />,
                User2: <Checkbox />,
              }
            ],
          },
          {
            key: 221,
            name: <p style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}> Function 2</p>,
            User1: '',
            User2: '',
            children: [
              {
                key: 2211,
                name: <p>Feature 1</p>,
                User1: <Checkbox />,
                User2: <Checkbox />,

              }
            ]
          }
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

return (
      <Table
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={data}
        pagination={{ pageSize: 5, hideOnSinglePage: true }}
      >
      </Table>
);
}
```

But in the Material-UI, I don't know how to create a Table like that!
I've only been learning ReactJS for a month and have just used this library for the first time.

Could you show me how to do it?
Thanks for reading!

(English isn’t my first language, so please excuse my mistakes!)

Comment: I think you should use Collapsible table. This is a simple example https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ftj02?file=/demo.js

Comment: yah.. Thanks for your solution @MaiTruong but I want to make a collapsable table inside a collapsed table row like in the picture

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to answer, but [Material React Table](https://www.material-react-table.com/) has the ability to group by row contents, or (more relevant to this question) use [subrows](https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/expanding-sub-rows) within other rows.

It uses MUI components internally, so it should work for you as long as you're already using MUI as well.